# Grey out sprite in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there an easy way to grey out a sprite?  I'm disabling a button, and I know how to do that, but wants to convey that in the GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply the ColorMatrixFilter to your Sprite with the approximate values that makes color greyscaled.

```
sprite.filters = [ new ColorMatrixFilter([0.3086, 0.6094, 0.0820, 0, 0, 0.3086, 0.6094, 0.0820, 0, 0, 0.3086, 0.6094, 0.0820, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]) ];
```